# iOS Firebase Flashlight/ElasticSearch Heroku Setup using Node.JS

Tags: node.js, heroku, firebase, flashlight, bonsai-elasticsearch

I'm building an iOS app in Swift with a Firebase backend. I need advanced search options for my app. I've been told I should use Flashlight/ElasticSearch via this github link https://github.com/firebase/flashlight

Assume my app's name is SneakerSearch and my

```
Firebase Project_ID is- sneakersearch-az12 
Firebase Web_API_Key is- abc123XYZ000...
Firebase App_Url is- gs://sneakersearch-az12.appspot.com
```

I need some advice with the steps for setting this up as I'm new to Heroku and Node.js. I never learned either before but I've already installed the Heroku tool belt and 'sudo gem heroku install' is done.

I've listed the github directions/steps and the the step(s) I took for each direction. I need assistance with directions: 1,4,5,6,9,10,12, and 15.

```
1.Install and run ElasticSearch or add Bonsai service via Heroku
```

1. I make an account at Heroku.

1.-QUESTION: Do I need to create the name of my app and deploy it after I've setup my Heroku account or should I wait until step #9?

```
2.git clone https://github.com/firebase/flashlight
```

2.I clone the above into my iOS app's project folder

```
3.npm install
```

3.At the prompt I first I run "npm init" then I run "npm install"

```
4. edit config.js (see comments at the top, you must set FB_URL and FB_SERVICEACCOUNT at a minimum)
```

4A.-QUESTION: What is "FB_SERVICEACCOUNT"? I'm using Firebase 3 and I couldn't find anything on a service account in my console. Is this another Firebase account that I have to setup for my project using node.js in addition to the Firebase swift project I've already made?

4B.-QUESTION: Where do I "edit config.js" and set my FB_URL and FB_SERVICEACCOUNT at? Should this be in my package.json file?

```
5.node app.js (run the app)
```

5.-QUESTION: In terminal I ran "node app.js" and got "throw err;^". Why did I get this error?

```
6.curl -X POST http://localhost:9200/firebase
```

6.-QUESTION: What is this for?

```
7.cd flashlight
```

7.switched to the flashlight dir

```
8.heroku login
```

8.logged in to Heroku

```
9.heroku create (add heroku to project)
```

9A-QUESTION: When I first made my account at Heroku should I have created a new app with my app's name and deployed it using the git instructions it has listed? If I should not have done that at first will running "heroku create" manage that process for me?

9B-QUESTION: Do I just run "heroku create" or do I run "heroku create -app's name- here"?

```
10.heroku addons:add bonsai (install bonsai)
```

10.-QUESTION: Do I need to make an account at Bonasi.io and install it before this step or does this set up a bonsai account for me? I've never used bonsai before.

```
11.heroku config (check bonsai instance info and copy your new BONSAI_URL - you will need it later)
```

11.I guess this question would depend on step #10.

```
12.heroku config:set FB_NAME=<instance> FB_TOKEN="<token>" (declare environment variables)
```

12.-QUESTION: What is the Firebase TOKEN? Is this my Web_API_Key, App_URL, or Project_ID? I could not find anything specific to "token" inside my firebase console. I'm using Firebase 3.

```
13.git add config.js (update)
git commit -m "configure bonsai"
```

13. commit with message

```
14.git push heroku master (deploy to heroku)
```

14. push to master

```
15.heroku ps:scale worker=1 (start dyno worker)
```

15.-QUESTION: What is this for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a 2 part answer with the 1st part going over the Github directions and ending on Step 19. The 2nd part extends more info that couldn't fit into the 1st part and it will begin on step 19 in detail. I'll have to add it to another question and link it to this.

Here are the `Github` steps listed in order. FYI I kept the original steps in line with how the original `Github author` listed them but underneath I put a bunch of sub-steps with detailed explanations and directions under each one.

Assuming you already created a `Firebase` project and got your `GoogleService-Info.plist` file

Open your `GoogleService-Info.plist` file. The following `variables` from the `Github directions` correlate with `GoogleService-Info.plist keys`

```
-FB_NAME is the same thing as your PROJECT_ID
-FB_URL is the same thing as your DATABASE_URL
-FB_TOKEN is the same thing as your API_KEY

So 

-if your PROJECT_ID is "sneakersearch-az12" then your FB_NAME is "sneakersearch-az12"
-if your DATABASE_URL is "https://sneakersearch-az12.firebaseio.com" then your FB_URL is "https://sneakersearch-az12.firebaseio.com"
-if your API_KEY is "0012abc789xyz00019" then your FB_TOKEN is "0012abc789xyz00019"

//These are not inside your GoogleService-Info.plist but you will encounter them later
-FB_SERVICEACCOUNT pertains to downloading a json file from the your project's Firebase console. You will need to go to the page SERVICE ACCOUNTS it's exp in step 3B
-clientEmail is the same thing as your Firebase Service Account. You get this from either the Unknown file or on your SERVICE ACCOUNTS page via the FB Console and it's exp in step 3D and 3B
-privateKey is the same thing as private_key but this key is NOT your API_KEY, it is a key that is inside the Unknown file from the SERVICE ACCOUNTS page. It looks something like: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nCYchgacopuyvpc017246t124087t6hpUTYVPUSVDPUCHVEpcl889ljbsiugr4ygrphvuygpuy...mutli-lines...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n". Also exp in step 3B
```

Underneath each `Github` step I have comments and then directions. Inside the directions where I use the below values you should instead use your `project's values`. So for the step examples I'll use these `keys` and `values`:

```
//GoogleService-Info.plist
PROJECT_ID---aka--FB_NAME:  sneakersearch-az12
DATABASE_URL-aka--FB_URL:   https://sneakersearch-az12.firebaseio.com
API_KEY------aka--FB_TOKEN: 0012abc789xyz00019
//FB Service Account info
Firebase service account--aka--clientEmail: firebase-admin-81772@sneakersearch-az12.iam.gserviceaccount.com //this is auto generated for you once you've created your firebase project
//Heroku and Bonsai info
Heroku Instance Name--aka--Heroku App Name: sneakersearchinstanceAtoZ
BONASI_URL --aka--Bonsai Cluster URL:  https://abc123a01:01abc12de45xyz34@xyz-012345.us-east-1.bonsaisearch.net
```

Swift Data Model: (this will match what you put in your mappings object in Step 19)

```
class Sneakers: NSObject{
    var sneakercondition: String?
    var sneakername: String?
 }
```

VC with file paths where I send data to Firebase and *searchSnkPath* is a separate file path where Bonsai will run it's searches on:

```
@IBOutlet weak var conditionTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!

var dbRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
 }

@IBAction func postDataButton(){

    var dict = [String:AnyObject]()
    dict.updateValue(conditionTextField.text!, forKey: "sneakercondition")
    dict.updateValue(nameTextField.text!, forKey: "sneakername")

    let idPath = self.dbRef.child("users").child(userID!).child("sneakersPath").childByAutoId()

        //searches will run on this file path
    let searchSnkPath = self.dbRef.child("searchSnkPath").childByAutoId()

    idPath.updateChildValues(dict){
       (err, ref) in
       searchSnkPath.updateChildValues(dict)
    }
  }
}
```

Inside `FBDatabase` the path where my data to search is stored at `root/searchSnkPath/autoID` and it has 2 `keys` named `sneakercondition` and `sneakername` that represents the data. The path I want to pull my search results from is `root/searchSnkPath`

```
root
  |
  @-users
  |   |
  |   @-userID
  |      |
  |      @-sneakersPath
  |            |
  |            @-autoID
  |                |-sneakercondition
  |                |-sneakername
  @searchSnkPath
      |
      @-autoID
          |-sneakercondition
          |-sneakername
```

If I want to search on the `searchSnkPath` and query on those 2 `keys` then inside the `config.js` file I'd find `exports.paths` and inside there is where I would set the info to search on

```
exports.paths = [
   {          
      path : "https://sneakersearch-az12.firebaseio.com/searchSnkPath", //exp in Step 4
      index: "firebase", //exp in Step 17
      type : "sneakers", //exp in Step 19
      fields: ['sneakercondition', 'sneakername'] //these are the specific keys to search on (exp in Step 4)
    }
]
```

Step 4 covers all this

**Important** after you run `git clone https://github.com/firebase/flashlight` (step 2A) you need to `cd` into the `flashlight` folder (step 2B) as ALL the steps from that point on happen inside the `flashlight` folder and **NOT** your main Xcode project's folder. **Nothing will not work inside your Xcode project's folder because it doesn't have a package.json file**

Part 1 - Github steps:

> 1•Install and run ElasticSearch or add Bonsai service via Heroku

**1.comments:**

-`Bonsai` will get added at step 10

-You DO need to have the following steps 1A-1E in order before you proceed

**1.directions:**

**1A.** Download and install `Node.js` from https://nodejs.org/en/download/

**1B.** Download and install the `Heroku Toolbelt` (it's been renamed `Heroku CLI`) at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli. FYI I used the OS X Installer and not OS X Homebrew.

**1C.** After you've downloaded and installed the `Heroku Toolbelt/CLI` log on to Heroku.com and create an account

**1D.** After creating a `Heroku` account no need to create a new `Heroku App` You will do this in step 9 using the command line. It's very easy

**1E.** Open terminal and run: `node -v` to find out the current `node version` your running (for example you get `v6.9.1`). In step 2D you will have to make sure the version from there matches this output.

> 2•git clone https://github.com/firebase/flashlight

**2.comments:**

-Assume the Xcode project lives on the desktop inside a folder named `sneakerSearchFolder`

-Inside terminal you `cd` to the sneakerSearchFolder folder- i.e. run: `cd Desktop/sneakerSearchFolder`

-Once inside the sneakerSearchFolder you `clone` `the github repo` at https://github.com/firebase/flashlight

-*Important* You then `cd` to `flashlight` folder i.e. run: `cd flashlight`

-You will need the `node version` your running according to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

-run: `node -v` to get what `node version` is running inside the `flashlight` folder (i.e `v6.9.1`) later on when you make a `Heroku instance` you will need this according to the `devcenter.heroku` link above

-Now that your inside the `flashlight` folder, if the `node version` you just ran doesn't match the version from step 1E, you will need to update the version inside the flashlight folder to make them match. [Upgrading Node.js to latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version) *If both versions match then you don't have to worry about this*

-Assuming your node versions match, Open the `package.json` file inside your `flashlight` folder and add an `"engines"` object with the key's value being the `node version` you are currently using

```
"engines": {
    "node": "node_version_num_you_got_back_from_running_node -v"
  }
```

**2.directions:**

**2A.** in terminal navigate to whatever folder your Xcode project is in

**2B.** run: `git clone https://github.com/firebase/flashlight`

**2C.** run: `cd flashlight`

**2D.** run: `node -v`

**2E.** Open the `flashlight` folder then open `package.json`. Add the following to the file.

```
"engines": {
    "node": "whatever_was_returned_from_Step_2D"
  }
```

**2E-example.** FYI here's an example. Open `package.json` and after the `"dependencies"` `closing brace`, add it there. BE SURE TO ADD a COMMA after the closing brace. And don't add the "v" before the version number. Save the file.

```
"dependencies": {
    "JQDeferred": "~1.9.1",
    "colors": "~0.6.2",
    "elasticsearch": "^11.0.1",
    "firebase": "^3.5.2"
  },
"engines": {
    "node": "6.9.1"
  }
```

> 3•npm install

*From this point on it's very important that your inside your `flashlight` folder and not your main project's folder for everything to work otherwise you will get errors*

**3.comments:**

-You should still be inside your `flashlight` folder

-Log into `Firebase`, inside the console of your FB project, go to the `Project's Settings` (little round icon next to `Overview`), inside Project Settings choose `SERVICE ACCOUNTS`, go to the section `Firebase Admin SDK`. There are 2 things you have to do here. 1. Find and copy your `Firebase service account`, it looks like *firebase-admin-81772@sneakersearch-az12.iam.gserviceaccount.com* and 2. at the bottom of the page you will have to click the `Generate New Private Key` button, it will download an `Unknown file` that you will need to rename to `service-account.json`. If it names the file something besides `Unknown` just rename that to `service-account.json`. After you rename the file drag it into your `flashlight` folder because Step 4B `FB_SERVICEACCOUNT` will need to access this file from there. MAKE SURE YOU PUT THE FILE INSIDE THE `FLASHLIGHT FOLDER`!

-This isn't listed in the github steps but it's necessary. You must add `Firebase Server SDK Credentials` to your project

-You will need to be inside your `flashlight` folder to run the $`npm install firebase-admin --save` command or you'll get errors because it will look for a `packae.json` file. The file is already inside your `flashlight` folder and not inside your main Xcode project's folder

-Follow the directions from https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup, inside the `Initialize the SDK` section. You will need 2 of the values from the `Unknown` file (which should now be renamed `service-account.json`) to initialize it. The values are on lines 5-`private_key` and 6-`clientEmail`. FYI the `clientEmail` and `Firebase service account` are the same thing

-Here's what you are `initializing` inside the `SDK`:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin"); //this imports the npm firebase-admin module you just installed

admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert({
        projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>", //projectId: is the PROJECT_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
        clientEmail: "foo@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com", //clientEmail: is on  line 6 in the Unknown file which is also your "Firebase service account" info
        privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<KEY>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n" //privateKey: is NOT your API_KEY/FB_TOKEN. Inside the Unknown file on line 5 there is a very long multiline "private_key" key. It looks something like "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nCYchgacopuyvpc017tEpcl889ljbsiugr4ygrphvuygpuy...mutli-lines...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n". You need to copy and paste it from there to here. Be sure to include the "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n and \n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
      }),
      databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com" //databaseURL: is the DATABASE_URL from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
    });
```

-FYI inside the `Initialize the SDK` section you also have the option of using the top part where it says `path/to/serviceAccountKey.json` and you can instead supply the path to the renamed Unknown file. I choose the bottom `inline` part as it was easier. If your following these steps you don't need to worry about this though.

-Inside the `flashlight` folder there is an `app.js` file, copy and paste the above code and put it at the top of the file

-Back inside terminal on the command line run: `npm install`

-If everything is all good the only warnings you should have are `No repository field` and `No license field`

**3.directions:**

**3A**. Make sure your inside the `flashlight` folder run: `pwd`

**3B.** Log into your `Firebase Console`'s `SERVICE ACCOUNTS` page and click the `Generate New Private Key` button to download an `Unknown` file.

**3C.** Rename the `Unknown` file to `service-account.json` and put the file inside your `flashlight` folder

**3D.** Inside the `service-account.json` file copy the `key` named `client_email` or you can copy the service account info on your `Firebase SERVICE ACCOUNTS` page

**3E.** Inside terminal run: `npm install firebase-admin --save`

**3F.** Copy what's inside the section `Initialize the SDK` and initialize the fields with these values:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: "sneakersearch-az12", //use your PROJECT_ID
    clientEmail: "firebase-admin-81772@sneakersearch-az12.iam.gserviceaccount.com", //clientEmail: is on  line 6 in the Unknown file
    privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nCYchgacopuyvpc017tEpcl889ljbsiugr4ygrphvuygpuy...mutli-lines...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n" //privateKey: is on line 5 in the Unknown file
  }),
  databaseURL: "https://sneakersearch-az12.firebaseio.com" //use your DATABASE_URL
});
```

**3G.** Inside the `flashlight` folder, open the `app.js` file, paste/save the above code inside of it with the correct values

**3H.** run: `npm install`

> 4•edit config.js (see comments at the top, you must set FB_URL and
>   FB_SERVICEACCOUNT at a minimum)

**4.comments:**

-Inside your `flashlight` folder there is a file named `config.example.js`, open it

-Inside this `config.example.js` file is where you find the `FB_URL` and `FB_SERVICEACCOUNT` variables (they are listed on lines 13 and 23)

-You need to change `exports.FB_URL = process.env.FB_URL || 'https://<YOUR APP>.firebaseio.com';` to `exports.FB_URL   = process.env.FB_URL || 'whatever_your_DATABASE_URL_is';` (be sure to put `whatever_your_DATABASE_URL_is` inside single or double quotes)

-on line 23 `exports.FB_SERVICEACCOUNT = process.env.FB_ACC || 'service-account.json';` is what is used to access the `service-account.json file` from step 3C (there is no need to add or change anything here as it will access it on it's own)

-You will now have to setup the path where your data sits at (like the *searchPath* used to send data to FB inside the ViewController above), the index (Step 17), and the type (similar to your data model) that you want to monitor on line 64,65, and 66

```
exports.paths = [
  {
    path : "users",//line 64
    index: "firebase",//line 65
    type : "user"//line 66
  },
```

-`path` is where your `data` sits at inside `FB`. It's where you want to pull search results from i.e. `<DATABASE_URL>/searchSnkPath`

-`index` exp in Step 17

-`type` exp in **Step 19**

-FYI lines 69-79 would set up another path that you would want to monitor. You can delete or comment these out if you want. You can also create more paths to monitor i.e. If you had a path `<DATABASE_URL>/searchClothingPath` then you would set up search on that also. You can also add more paths if you want to i.e:

```
exports.paths = [
    {
      path : "https://sneakersearch-az12.firebaseio.com/searchSnkPath"
      index: "firebase",
      type : "sneakers"
    },
    {
      path : "<DATABASE_URL>/searchClothingPath"
      index: "firebase",
      type : "clothingDataModel",
      fields: ['jeans','shirts']//completely optional to use
    },
    {
      path : "<DATABASE_URL>/searchHatsPath"
      index: "firebase",
      type : "hatDataModel",
    },
    //etc...
```

-FYI `Fields` are the `keys` that will be indexed in ES. This is an optional thing to add. If you had 10 `keys` and only wanted 2 of them to be `indexed` then you would add this. This means of the 10 keys only those 2 `keys` would be searchable. You can also use the *parse function* inside the `config.js` file to do the same thing

-Afterwards save/close the `config.example.js` and rename it `config.js`

**4.directions:**

**4A.** Open the `config.example.js` file and on line 13 change `exports.FB_URL = process.env.FB_URL || 'https://<YOUR APP>.firebaseio.com';` to `exports.FB_URL = process.env.FB_URL || 'https://sneakersearch-az12.firebaseio.com';`

**4B.** Line 23 is what is used to access the `service-account.json` file (as long as you renamed the `Unknown file` in step 3C just move on)

**4C.** Line 64,65,66, are what I want to monitor and on line 67 I added the `fields key` for the two `Firebase Database Keys` I want to search on although it is not necessary

```
exports.paths = [
  {
    path : "https://sneakersearch-az12.firebaseio.com/searchSnkPath",//line 64
    index: "firebase",//line 65
    type : "sneakers",//line 66
    fields: ['sneakercondition', 'sneakername']//line 67
  },
```

**4D.** Save/close the `config.example.js` file. Now rename the file `config.js`.

> 5•node app.js (run the app)

**5.comments:**

-You won't run this command until the very end so skip it for now but there is something you should know. Running `node app.js` runs your Heroku app on your local machine. It will look for ElasticSearch locally which you don't have so you will get connection errors. If you want to run it locally then you will have to run the `export BONSAI_URL="<your_bonsai_url>"` code at Step 12B-Optional which is needed to resolve local connection errors. If your app falls asleep/crashes (exp near the end) you will have to run the `export BONSAI_URL="<your_bonsai_url>"` command again. Other then that Heroku will run the app automatically when you push code up to it.

-As of now for this step you need to open your `app.js` file and according to https://docs.bonsai.io/docs/nodejs add some code. You should add the code anywhere after the `var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch')` declaration.

```
/*
this code is already inside the app.js file. You should add the code anywhere below it

var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch'),
  conf = require('./config'),
  fbutil = require('./lib/fbutil'),
  PathMonitor = require('./lib/PathMonitor'),
  SearchQueue = require('./lib/SearchQueue');
*/

//You need to add
var bonsai_url = process.env.BONSAI_URL;
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
                         host: bonsai_url,
                         log: 'trace' 
                     });
    // Test the connection...
client.ping({
    requestTimeout: 30000,
    hello: "elasticsearch"
  },
  function (error) {
    if (error) {
      console.error('>>>My Bonsai url is>>>' + bonsai_url)
      console.error('>>>Elasticsearch cluster is down!');
    } else {
      console.log('All is well');
    }
  }
);
```

-The directions also says to run $ `export BONSAI_URL="https://username:password@my-awesome-cluster-123.us-east-1.bonsai.io"` (in other words `export BONSAI_URL="<your_BONSAI_URL>"`) which is what you would do ONLY if you want to run your app locally to use ES. It's not meant for remote

**5.directions:**

**5.** Open the `app.js` file and add the code below and save the file:

```
var bonsai_url = process.env.BONSAI_URL;
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
                         host: bonsai_url,
                         log: 'trace' 
                     });
    // Test the connection...
client.ping({
    requestTimeout: 30000,
    hello: "elasticsearch"
  },
  function (error) {
    if (error) {
      console.error('>>>My Bonsai url is>>>' + bonsai_url)
      console.error('>>>Elasticsearch cluster is down!');
    } else {
      console.log('All is well');
    }
  }
);
```

> 6•curl -X POST http://localhost:9200/firebase

**6.comments:**

-Skip this step because at this point you don't have a local `ES` on your cpu to index

**6.directions:**

**6.** SKIP THIS STEP

> 7•cd flashlight

**7.comments:**

-No need to run this, you should still be inside your `flashlight` folder

**7.directions:**

**7.** SKIP THIS STEP

> 8•heroku login

**8.comments:**

-Open terminal

-You will have to enter your `Heroku`'s `email address` and `password.` As you enter the password it will show up blank

**8.directions:**

**8A.** run: `heroku login`

**8B.** At the prompt enter your `email address` and `password` to login into Heroku

> 9•heroku create (add heroku to project)

**9.comments:**

-This is why you didn't need to create a `heroku` app at step 1D. Now you will create and name your heroku app

-After you type in `create` you need to type in whatever name you want your heroku app's name to be. i.e. I choose the name `sneakersearchinstanceAtoZ`

-After you run this command if you login into `Heroku` and you should see the app's name listed. Go to the right corner, click the `9 dots`, choose `Dashboard`

**9.directions:**

**9.** run: `heroku create sneakersearchinstanceAtoZ`

> 10•heroku addons:add bonsai (install bonsai)

**10.comments:**

-You will need to add a `credit card` to your `Heroku` account before you run this step otherwise after you run it it will say you have to do it. It's still a free plan though. I'm not sure if you can add a `Bonsai add on` without a card

-To add a credit card go all the way to the right side, click the circular icon, choose `Account Settings`, then choose `Billing`

-You now need to add `bonsai` to your `heroku app`. You do this by running `heroku addons:add bonsai --app <your-app-name>`

-`<your-app-name>` is whatever the `heroku` app's name you created in step 9

-after you create a `bonsai cluster` it will then want you to open up the cluster by running `heroku addons:open bonsai`

**10.directions:**

**10A.** log on to `Heroku` and add a credit card to the `Billing Page`

**10B.** run: `heroku addons:add bonsai --app sneakersearchinstanceAtoZ`//same exact name from step 9

**10C.** run `heroku addons:open bonsai`

> 11•heroku config (check bonsai instance info and copy your new
>   BONSAI_URL you will need it later)

**11.comments:**

-Running `heroku config` will get all your `environment variables` and their corresponding values. When you see your `bonsai's url`, copy it's value, you'll need it for steps 12B and 17

-This is the exact same url you will see from step 10C

-The `bonsai url` might look something like `https://abc123a01:01abc12de45xyz34@xyz-012345.us-east-1.bonsaisearch.net`

**11.directions:**

**11A.** run: `heroku config`

**11B.** Copy the `bonsai url` that is returned

> 12•heroku config:set FB_NAME= FB_TOKEN="" (declare
>   environment variables)

**12.comments:**

-12A is REQUIRED. You need to use your project's `GoogleService-Info.plist`'s `PROJECT_ID` which is the `FB_NAME` and the `API_KEY` which is the `FB_TOKEN` for this step

-12B is optional. If you want to connect to `ElasticSearch` locally run this. You will have to set your `bonsai url` so that running `node app.js` won't throw connection errors. You do this by running: `export BONSAI_URL="<your_bonsai_url>"`. You will need to run this command per terminal session or if your Heroku app falls asleep/crashes.

-Do not use spaces before or after the equal sign

**12.directions:**

**12A(REQUIRED).** run: `heroku config:set FB_NAME=sneakersearch-az12 FB_TOKEN=0012abc789xyz00019`

**12B(Optional)**.run: `export BONSAI_URL="https://abc123a01:01abc12de45xyz34@xyz-012345.us-east-1.bonsaisearch.net"`

> 13•git add config.js (update)

**13.comments:**

-If you run this you might get an error that says:
*The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
config.js
Use -f if you really want to add them.*

-It's saying to run `git add config.js` then add `-f` at the end

**13.directions:**

**13A.** run: `git add config.js`

**13B.** If there is an error run: `git add config.js -f`

> 14•git commit -m "configure bonsai"

**14.directions:**

**14.** run: `git commit -m "configure bonsai"`

> 15•git push heroku master (deploy to heroku)

**15.directions:**

**15.** run: `git push heroku master`

> 16•heroku ps:scale worker=1 (start dyno worker)

**16.comments:**

-the answer to what this command does is here [Can someone explain "heroku ps:scale web=1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318369/can-someone-explain-heroku-psscale-web-1)

**16.directions:**

**16.** run: `heroku ps:scale worker=1`

> 17•curl -X POST /firebase (ex:
>   https://username:password@yourbonsai.bonsai.io/firebase)

**17.comments:**

-**Before you begin this step read @DoesData updated answer (below mines) to use curl -X PUT instead of POST**

-Grab the `bonsai url` you copied from step 11B

-Paste the url after the `curl -X POST` command and make sure you add `/firebase` to the end of it

-what this does is it creates an index named `/firebase` that points to your `bonsai url`. Open your `config.js` file and look for `exports.paths` (line 62). That has a key/value pair named `index: "firebase"`(line 65) , the value is pointing to the index you just created and accesses the ES cluster from there

-Basically in your config.js file, on line 65 the `index` value `firebase` has to exactly match the name `/firebase` that your adding to the end `curl -X POST` command. If the names don't match then none of this will work.

-if successful you should get this response back: `{"acknowledged":true}`

**17.directions:**

**17.** run: `curl -X POST https://abc123a01:01abc12de45xyz34@xyz-012345.us-east-1.bonsaisearch.net/firebase`

> 18•Now time to use Step 5 node app.js (run the app)

**18.comments:**

-running this command will start the app locally. You can also run `npm start` but either way it will launch it on your local machine and you will need to run the code in Step 12B(Optional) for this to work

**18.directions**

**18.** run: `node app.js`

> 19• set your mappings object(s)

**FYI Step 19 is very important. You MUST set your MAPPINGS OBJECT and it's KEYS. I don't have enough chars left to explain it in detail here. This is what Step 4's `type` key uses to get set by. Watch this video to  explain how to set your `mappings object`:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3i3pqwjtjA&feature=youtu.be

**19.directions:**

**19A.** --open `TextEdit` or `Sublime` then create a file and name it `sneakerfile.json`. Save it and drag the file into your `flashlight` folder. You need the `.json` extension.

**19B.** -Inside that file add the following code, save and close the file:

```
{
  "sneakers": {
     "properties": {
       "sneakercondition": {
         "type": "string"
       },
       "sneakername": {
         "type": "string"
       }
     }
  }
}
//notice this is just like the Swift Sneakers Data Model declared at the beginning
```

**19C.** grab your `BONSAI_URL` run `heroku config:get BONSAI_URL`. My *BONSAI_URL* is *https://abc123a01:01abc12de45xyz34@xyz-012345.us-east-1.bonsaisearch.net*

**19D.** run: `curl -XPOST https://abc123a01:01abc12de45xyz34@xyz-012345.us-east-1.bonsaisearch.net/firebase/sneakers/_mapping -d@sneakerfile.json`

**19E.** run: `curl -XGET <BONASI_URL>/firebase/sneakers/_mapping?pretty`

*Done with Part 1. Part 2 will explain Step 19 in detail*

Further Info-

*Heroku commands:*

To check on your `dyno`

run: `heroku ps`

If you get the following then refer to the links below

```
=== web (Free): npm start (1)
web.1: crashed 2017/01/01 12:00:00 -0500 (~ 38m ago)

=== worker (Free): node ./app.js (1)
worker.1: crashed 2017/01/01 12:00:00 -0500 (~ 10m ago)
```

After creating your `Heroku app` your `dyno` is under the `Heroku Free Plan`. It will eventually `fall asleep`/`crash` if it's not being used within a certain time frame. To stop sleeping/crashing follow

[Easy way to prevent Heroku idling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480337/easy-way-to-prevent-heroku-idling)

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

*Other commands:*

```
heroku help //help
heroku status //Heroku platform status
heroku logs //displays 100 logs
heroku logs --tail //realtime logs
heroku logs --tail | grep worker //dyno worker logs
heroku ps -a <heroku app name> //how many dyno hrs you have left
heroku config:get BONSAI_URL //gets only your bonsai url
heroku config //all your environment variables
heroku apps:info //your Heroku credentials
```

**To get back to the** `command prompt` **press** `Ctrl+C`

*You can also contact Heroku Support or Bonsai Support as they are very helpful*

*I will post Part 2 very soon.*

Comment: Hi @Lance Samaria, when will you post the part 2? This is what I've been looking for!!! `iOS` + `ElasticSearch` + `Firebase`! Thank you so much!

Comment: @ prettyitgirl.com hi gimme 2 weeks. The reason being it's a lot of work and I'm still unclear with a few things.For step 19 you need to set your mappings key with a file. Create a file: sneaker file.json and inside the file: {
   "sneakers": {
      "properties": {
        "sneakercondition": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "sneakername": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
   }
} and then on the cli set the key like this: curl -XPOST <BONSAI_URL>/firebase/sneakers/_mappings -d@sneakerfile.json then run: curl -XGET <BONSAI_URL>/firebase/_mappings?pretty

Comment: @ prettyitgirl.com this video explains it very well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3i3pqwjtjA&feature=youtu.be .Step 19 is based off of this video. In step 4 this is how you set the 'type' and 'fields' key. Even without the 'fields' key you have to do this step. Just watch the video then try to follow my comment above. If your lost I'll come back later or another day and walk you through it.

Comment: @prettyitgirl.com I forgot to say that if you want to make flashlight accessible by the client you have to make an api call from the client to flashlight and back. So in your iOS app inside your searchController you make the api call from there to flashlight and flashlight does the search in firebase and returns the results to the updateSearchResultsForSearchController method.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151833/discussion-on-answer-by-lance-samaria-ios-firebase-flashlight-elasticsearch-hero).

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is great. However, there are far too many comments for my update to be useful there so I'm placing it here.

If you follow the above steps you will encounter an error on step:

17. run: curl -X POST https://abc123a01:01abc12de45xyz34@xyz-012345.us-east-1.bonsaisearch.net/firebase

Newer versions of elasticSearch no longer allow you to create a new index using POST, but you can use PUT. So you want to run

```
curl -X PUT https://abc123a01:01abc12de45xyz34@xyz-012345.us-east-1.bonsaisearch.net/firebase
```

and the response should be: `{"acknowledged":true,"shards_acknowledged":true}`

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186222/no-handler-found-for-uri-myindex-and-method-post-elasticsearch-5-0-3-with) for more information.

**Update**

I also switched over to Algolia because the documentation was a lot more clear. However, I would say that the elastic search documentation is in drastic need of an update. I would recommend that those interested in elastic search try to deploy their code using Firebase cloud functions rather than Heroku. I haven't been able to find a guide for this, but the node.js code should be similar except it will be deployed to the Firebase cloud instead of Heroku. This should make the process a lot simpler. You can check out Firebase cloud functions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases)

Comment: I had to many chars to add everything you wrote so I had to delete some words here and there. At the bottom of the directions on Step 17 in bold I said if they get an error to read your updated answer. Also some people may still have the older version and the GitHub author still has "curl X Post" on the page.

Comment: you should put an example of what the error will look like if someone uses the Post command instead of the Put command. I'm actually curious myself because I'm going to have to go through this again for another project.