# 'No handler found for uri [/myindex] and method [POST]' Elasticsearch 5.0.3 with nodejs esclient

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I am trying to create an index using the npm package [elasticsearch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch) and have been recieving the following error.

'No handler found for uri [/myindex] and method [POST]'

`esClient.indices.create({
 index: 'myindex'
 }, function(err, resp, status) {
     cb(err, resp);
});`

The following code was working for Elasticsearch 2.3

**Here is the tracelog**

```
Elasticsearch DEBUG: 2017-04-03T13:54:24Z
  starting request { method: 'POST', path: '/myindex1', query: {} }


Elasticsearch TRACE: 2017-04-03T13:54:24Z
  -> POST http://localhost:9200/myindex1

  <- 400
  No handler found for uri [/myindex1] and method [POST]

Elasticsearch DEBUG: 2017-04-03T13:54:24Z
  Request complete

{ Error: Bad Request
    at respond (/Users/Ut/Fitternity/metropolis/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:293:15)
    at checkRespForFailure (/Users/Ut/Fitternity/metropolis/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:252:7)
    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/Users/Ut/Fitternity/metropolis/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:155:
7)
    at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/Users/Ut/Fitternity/metropolis/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3095
:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:926:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
  status: 400,
  displayName: 'BadRequest',
  message: 'Bad Request' } 'No handler found for uri [/myindex1] and method [POST]' 400
[ 'No handler found for uri [/myindex1] and method [POST]' ]
```

Comment: Can you also show how you create your `esClient`?

Comment: var esClient = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: config.es.host,
    log: 'error'
});

Comment: have you updated your JavaScript client as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your JavaScript client as well and instantiate it with the [`apiVersion` parameter set to `5.0`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/configuration.html#config-options)

```
var esClient = new elasticsearch.Client({ 
   host: config.es.host, 
   log: 'error',
   apiVersion: '5.0'
});
```

The reason for this is that as ES 5.0 it is not possible to create a new index using the `POST` HTTP method, but only with the `PUT` method

Comment: Hey @Val i am facing the same issue with rails can you please tell me how can i fix it?

Comment: @awsmsid feel free to create a new question explaining your exact problem.

Comment: Sure let me create a new question.

Comment: Hey @Val please check my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50291905/no-handler-found-for-uri-index-type-and-method-post