# No handler found for uri [/<index>/<type>/] and method [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

Hi i am working on a RoR project with ruby-2.4.0 and rails 5. I am using elasticsearch for searching in my app. I have a model venue_details as follows:-

```
class VenueDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  settings index: { 
    number_of_shards: 1, 
    number_of_replicas: 0,
  } do
    mapping do
      indexes :id, :index => :not_analyzed
      indexes :venue_name, :type => 'string', :index => :analyzed
    end
  end

  def self.search(params)
    if params[:query].present?
      tire.search(load: true) do
        query { string "*#{params[:query]}*", default_operator: "AND" }
         size 100
      end      
    else
      tire.search(load: true) do
        query { string "*#{params[:term]}*", default_operator: "AND"}
         size 100
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

I am using the elasticsearch-5.1.2. I am trying to reindex the venue details with command `rake environment tire:import CLASS=VenueDetail FORCE=true` it throws an error as follows:-

```
There has been an error when creating the index -- elasticsearch returned:
400 : No handler found for uri [/venue_details] and method [POST]
```

Please help how can i fix it. Thanks in advance.