# Firebase Flashlight - Bonsai-ElasticSearch API Call to perform search

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, flashlight, bonsai-elasticsearch

I have just implemented `Firebase Flashlight` with `Bonsai ElasticSearch` in order to be able to perform advance queries for my data in my iOS app.

I have done so following this tutorial: [iOS Firebase Flashlight/ElasticSearch Heroku Setup using Node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231771/ios-firebase-flashlight-elasticsearch-heroku-setup-using-node-js)

The problem I have is, that at the end, having the Node.js app running on Heroku, I am not sure how to proceed and use it in order to perform the searches in my iOS app.

From my understanding, so far, I have to perform a API call to my `Bonsai-ElasticSearch`, from there it will use the `Flashlight` app in order to return my desired results.

The problem is I am not sure how to do this, as you can tell, I am new to using `Flashlight` or `Bonsai-ElasticSearch`. If you have any advice on how I could do this, or at least point me to the right direction, would be amazing. Thanks