# Firebase/Flashlight Elastic Search

Tags: firebase, elasticsearch, heroku, firebase-realtime-database

[I was using this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231771/ios-firebase-flashlight-elasticsearch-heroku-setup-using-node-js) by Lance Samaria to integrate firebase flashlight into Heroku with the bonsai add-on for elastic search. On step 17 after I run the curl post I get this error `No handler found for uri [/firebase] and method [POST]`. Where is this error coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by using cURL PUT instead of cURL POST

Comment: Since Lance never posted part two were you ever able to get the whole setup to work? How are you sending information to flashlight? Can you share some code on how you are performing searches from within your app?

Comment: Actually I could never get flashlight to work. So right now, I am using algolia instead. It is very easy to set up and it only took me half an hour. I suggest you do the the same. However algolia also does have outrageously expensive pricing plans. I will be able to share some code next Wednesday.